# How can I avoid the repetition of returning InternalServerError in failure cases?

Tags: go, error-handling, http-status-codes, code-duplication, go-http

I'm trying to add a function for error handling to my web app and instead of doing this all the time

```
if err != nil {
   http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
   return
}
```

do something like this :

```
ErrorHandler(err)
```

I made this function :

```
func ErrorHandler(w *http.ResponseWriter, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(*w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
        // break the go routine
    }
}
```

but i don't know how can i break the handler when error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't break the handler when an error occurs. There are ways to do this cleanly, but the first option (using `http.Error`) is pretty good as well.

One option is to write the handler as:

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err:=func() {
       // Do stuff
       if err!=nil {
         return err
       }
    }()
    if err!=nil {
       http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
    }
}
```

Another option is to use a middleware-like pattern:

```
func CheckError(hnd func(http.ResponseWriter,*http.Request) error) func(http.ResponseWriter,*http.Request) {
   return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
      err:=hnd(w,req)
      if err!=nil {
         // Deal with the error here
      }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this as a handler:

```
CheckError(handler)
```

where

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) error {
}
```